# calling target exec power shell command that has spaces in file paths

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, target

I am trying to call a BAT via a Visual Studio Target exec command but it errors out when there are spaces in the file path. I tried enclosing it with a `&quot;` but it still fails.

Error:

```
1>Task "CreateProperty" (TaskId:58)
1>  Task Parameter:Value=C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat (TaskId:58)
1>  Output Property: batPath=C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat (TaskId:58)
1>Done executing task "CreateProperty". (TaskId:58)
1>Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Exec" (TaskId:59)
1>  Task Parameter:Command=%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat" "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager\bin\2018\HOK.BetaToolsManager.dll" (TaskId:59)
1>  %WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat" "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager\bin\2018\HOK.BetaToolsManager.dll" (TaskId:59)
1>  C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK : The term 'C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK' is  (TaskId:59)
1>  not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or  (TaskId:59)
1>  if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. (TaskId:59)
1>  At line:1 char:1 (TaskId:59)
1>  + C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK. ... (TaskId:59)
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (TaskId:59)
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\ksobon...evit-Addins\HOK:String) [], CommandNotFoundException (TaskId:59)
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException (TaskId:59)
1>    (TaskId:59)
1>C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager.csproj(332,5): error MSB3073: The command "%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat" "C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager\bin\2018\HOK.BetaToolsManager.dll"" exited with code 1.
1>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:59)
1>Done building target "CopyFiles" in project "HOK.BetaToolsManager.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:82)
```

Here's my target call:

```
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <CreateProperty Value="$(SolutionDir)..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat">
      <Output PropertyName="batPath" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>
    <Exec Command="%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe &quot;$(batPath)&quot; &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;"/>
  </Target>
```

The error is pretty clear about what the issue is. The path has spaces in it and makes power shell think that's a command. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `\"` and `\`"` instead of `&quot;`?

Comment: I have not. Please post an answer and I will gladly test it out.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is described in this article: [Executing a Windows PowerShell Script on the Build Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files#executing-a-windows-powershell-script-on-the-build-server). Generally, the command should be: `powershell.exe   –command &quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;[Path to script]&apos; 
                        &apos;[parameter1]&apos; 
                        &apos;[parameter2]&apos; } &quot;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have access to a build server to test it, but following the instructions written in this [Executing a Windows PowerShell Script on the Build Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files#executing-a-windows-powershell-script-on-the-build-server) article, it should be close to:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' "> 
      %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    </PowerShellExe>
    <BatPath Condition=" '$(BatPath)'=='' ">
      C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat
    </BatPath>
    <TargetPath Condition=" '$(TargetPath)'=='' ">
      C:\Users\ksobon\source\repos\HOK-Revit-Addins\HOK Beta Tools\src\HOK.BetaToolsManager\HOK.BetaToolsManager\bin\2018\HOK.BetaToolsManager.dll
    </TargetPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted 
                 -command &quot;&amp; { 
                          &amp;&apos;$(BatPath)&apos; 
                          &apos;$(TargetPath)&apos;} &quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: thanks for posting the link to that article. The above didn't exactly work for me but it got me on the right track. This worked: `<Exec Command="&quot;%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(SolutionDir)..\..\..\_postBuild\codeSigning.bat&apos; &apos;$(TargetPath)&apos; } &quot;" />`

Comment: Just to elaborate. For some reason if I didn't have the double quotes around the `powershell` file path, it would error out. Also, putting all of the variables on a single line fixed all other issues that I was having with improper spaces, quotes etc. For some reason msbuild didn't like the multi line style that the above example was written in. Anyways, I was able to get it fixed, and that's thanks to your suggestion to look at `-command` way of calling `powershell`. Thanks!